# Как показывать блок в определённые дни недели?

Tags: javascript

Есть код:

```js
$(function() {
  var d = new Date()
  var time = d.getHours()
  if (time >= 8 && time < 16) {
    $("#alrt_b").css("display", "block");
  } else {
    $("#alrt_b2").css("display", "block");
  }
});
```

```css
#alrt_b,
#alrt_b2 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="alrt_b">Первый текст</div>
<div id="alrt_b2">Второй текст</div>
```

Он показывает в определенное время текст один, а в другое время другой.

Как можно сделать, чтобы текст показывался только с понедельника по пятницу или только в выходные?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date
у даты много методов, в тч есть `getDay()` – день недели

Comment: В чем у вас возникла проблема с чтением документации?

Comment: в java не очень силён

Comment: Вам очень повезло, что это не Java

Comment: перепутал. js / мне бы пример реализации

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например так, а вообще, как Вам и советовали в комментариях, стоит ознакомиться с документацией.

```js
$(function() {
  let day = new Date().getDay();
  $((day >= 1 && day <= 5) ? "#alrt_b" : "#alrt_b2").css("display", "block");
});
```

```css
#alrt_b,
#alrt_b2 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="alrt_b">Пн-Пт</div>
<div id="alrt_b2">Сб-Вс</div>
```